# Uploading an Image using SQL and Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, dao

Im stuck on trying to upload an Image with my Java Code. I am using a Data Access Object and have the ojdbc5 and ordim libraries.
The main problem I have is trying to insert an image using the following line of code: stmtInsert.setImage(8, ORDSYS.ORDImage.init());

I have been stuck at this point for ages.

```
public void createImageInfo(           
                                     final String user_ID,
                                     final int photo_ID,
                                     final int num_views,
                                     final double price,
                                     final String photo_Name,
                                     final String imageCategory,
                                     final Calendar dateUploaded,
                                     final ORDSYS.ORDImage.init(image))
{


    PhotoSysDAO result = null;
    PreparedStatement stmtInsert = null;

    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle server",
                    "username", "password"); 
                    //open a connection to db...needs your account and password

        //int ratingID = RatingsDAO.getUniqueRatingId(conn);

        StringBuilder sbInsert = new StringBuilder();


        sbInsert.append("INSERT INTO ");
        sbInsert.append("Photos");
        sbInsert.append(" VALUES (");

        sbInsert.append("SequenceSet.seq_photo_id.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    Calendar date =  Calendar.getInstance();

                    stmtInsert.setInt(1, photo_ID);
        stmtInsert.setString(2, user_ID);
        stmtInsert.setInt(3, num_views);
                    stmtInsert.setDouble(4, price);
                    stmtInsert.setString(5, photo_Name);
                    stmtInsert.setString(6, imageCategory);
                    stmtInsert.setString(7, new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy").format(date));
                    //stmtInsert.setImage(8, photo.ORDSYS.ORDIMGB);
                    stmtInsert.setImage(8, ORDSYS.ORDImage.init()); 
        int rows = stmtInsert.executeUpdate();

        if (rows != 1)
        {
            throw new SQLException("executeUpdate return value: " + rows);
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {   
        System.out.println("There was an error in connecting to the database");
    }
    finally
    {
        PhotoSysDAO.closeStatement(stmtInsert);
        PhotoSysDAO.closeJDBCConnection(conn);
    }
    //return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you dont't use the sbInsert variable after sbInsert.append("SequenceSet...")

Comment: That code will throw a NullPointerException at `stmtInsert.setInt(1, photo_ID);`, since stmtInsert is never initialized. What is your exact problem?

Comment: What is the full name of your `PreparedStatement` class. Usually PreparedStatement cannot `setImage`, but you can help by using `setBlob`instead and use `..., ?, ORDSYS.ORDImage.init(?))` in your statement. Have your image as a byte[] or as a File, then you can make a `ByteArrayInputStream` or a `FileInputStream` from it to pass to `setBlob`.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion to you, not storing image in Database, you will harm your database storage & performance.
Store your photo on folder location & store the path in the database.